# How to iterate through a date range in c++

Tags: c++, date, loops, iteration

I have a folder with csv files. Each csv file is named by a date (eg. 01JAN2013.csv, 02JAN2013.csv ). I have to read the files in the order of their date (start date and end date are known).

So I am trying to loop through the dates, from the start date to the end date, in order to generate the file names.

Currently I am doing:

```
vector<string> dd{"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09","10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"};
vector<string> mmm{"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG","SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"};
vector<string> yyyy{"2011","2012","2013","2014"};

string filePath=DataFolderPath;

for(int i=0;i<yyyy.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<mmm.size();j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<dd.size();k++)
        {
            filePath.append(dd[k]);
            filePath.append(mmm[j]);
            filePath.append(yyyy[i]);
            filePath.append(".csv");
        }
    }
}
```

Definitely ugly, but it gets the job done.

Is there an easier way to loop through dates in C++. Something along the lines of:

```
for ( currentDate = starDate; currentDate < endDate; currentDate++) {

//Do stuff

 }
```

---

UPDATE:

This is the approach that I finally used, combination of both the answers below:

```
typdef struct tm Time;
Time startDate=makeDate(3,1,2011);
Time endDate=makeDate(24,1,2014);
time_t end=mktime(&endDate);

for(Time date=startDate;end>=mktime(&date);++date.tm_mday)
{
    char buffer[16];
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d%b%Y.csv", &date);

    std::string filename(buffer);
            //To convert month to CAPS
    std::transform(filename.begin()+2, filename.begin()+5,filename.begin()+2, ::toupper);


    std::cout << filename << "\n";
}
```

I also used a `makeDate` helper function based on paddy's answer which return a `struct tm` instead of `time_t`:

```
Time makeDate( int day, int month, int year )
{
Time ttm = {0};
ttm.tm_mday= day;
ttm.tm_mon= month-1;
ttm.tm_year= year-1900;
return ttm;
}
```

Comment: Seems like it'd be easier to find the files that are there, then just sort them by date, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Each file just contains the data for a given date. It was not created/modified on that date. SO sorting the files by date will not be helpfull.

Comment: No, I mean sorting by the date in the name.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That sounds simple, but I have no idea, how to do that...

Comment: Could you have it as ddmmyyyy, eg 31012014, instead of 31Jan2014? OR 31_01_2014, or some variant? Just because I expect sorting by month will become alphabetical in the current form.

Comment: @chrisb2244 I dont have any control over the file name pattern.

Answer (score 7):

It might not actually be easier....  But you can use the time functions from `<ctime>`.  Something like this:

```
string MakeFileName( time_t t )
{
    static const char* months[] = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
                                    "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC" };
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&t);

    char buffer[20];
    snprintf( buffer, 20, "%02d%s%04d.CSV",
              ptm->tm_day, months[ptm->tm_month], ptm->tm_year+1900 );

    return string(buffer);
}
```

Now just get your start and end dates correct in a `time_t` value (remember, it's in seconds).  You can just use `00:00:00` for the time.

```
// Note that day and month are 1-based.
time_t GetDate( int day, int month, int year )
{
    struct tm ttm = {0};
    ttm.tm_day = day;
    ttm.tm_month = month-1;
    ttm.tm_year = year-1900;
    return mktime(&ttm);
}
```

With that helper you can set your start and end dates easily:

```
time_t start = GetDate(1, 1, 2011);
time_t end = GetDate(28, 10, 2013);
for( time_t t = start; t <= end; t += 86400 )
{
    string filename = MakeFileName(t);

    // TODO...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to generate the names, I think @paddy has the right general idea, but the implementation may be open to a little improvement. In particular, `mktime` not only does conversions, it can...fix its input, so if you give it an input of 30 Feb, it knows that's either 1 or 2 March, and will change it appropriately. Likewise, it knows that `32 December 2011` is really `1 Jan 2012` and (again) adjusts the input appropriately.

At a guess, you also probably don't really want to generate dates into the future, and just had it generating dates through the end of the year because you didn't want to modify it every date. I'm guessing just generating dates up through the date it's run is probably sufficient.

With those in mind, I'd write the code more like this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    struct tm date;

    date.tm_mon = 1;
    date.tm_mday = 1;
    date.tm_year = 2011 - 1900;

    time_t end = time(NULL);

    for (; mktime(&date) < end; ++date.tm_mday) {
        char buffer[16];

        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d%b%Y", &date);
        std::cout << buffer << "\t";
    }
}
```

For the moment this just prints out the strings, but with them generated correctly, using them as file names will normally be pretty trivial.

If you want to do as I suggested in the comment, and get all the file names, then sort them into order by date, you can convert each file name to a `time_t`, the sort the `time_t`s. One fairly easy way to do that is with the `std::get_time` manipulator:

```
time_t cvt(std::string const &filename) { 
    std::istringstream in(filename);
    struct tm date;

    in >> std::get_time(&date, "%d%b%Y");
    return mktime(date);
}
```

With this, you could (for one possibility) put the `time_t`s and file names into a `std::map`, then just walk through the map from beginning to end, and process each file in order.

```
std::map<time_t, std::string> files;
std::string file_name;

while (get_file_name(&file_name))
    files[cvt(file_name)] = file_name;

for (auto const &f : files)
    process(f.second);
```

Comment: Why is the size of the buffer 16? When there are only 9 chars?

Comment: @ShayanRC: I pretty routinely round most sizes to powers of two.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::gregorian;

long dateDifference( string start_date, string end_date ) 
{
    date _start_date(from_simple_string(start_date));
    date _end_date(from_simple_string(end_date));

    for(day_iterator iter = _start_date; iter!=_end_date; ++iter)
    {
       // Do what you want
    }
}
```